# How to define a component with default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my component (`Amount.tsx`):

```
export const Amount = ({price, prevPrice}) => {
  return (
    <div className="product-amount">
      <div className="price">
        {prevPrice ? (<del className="prev">{Number(prevPrice).toLocaleString()} تومان </del>) : ''}
        <ins className="current">{${Number(price).toLocaleString()} تومان }</ins>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to call this component without default value. for example:

```
return (
<Amount />
)
```

Comment: so, what should is show in that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using destructuring defaults:

```
export const Amount = ({price = defaultForPrice, prevPrice = defaultForPrevPrice} = {}) => {
// #1 −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

With a normal function, you'd also need to provide a default value for the parameter as a whole (adding `= {}` after the closing `}` on the destructuring), but not with a component function, since they're always passed a props object (even if an empty one).

Comment: FWIW, I go into destructuring defaults (and parameter destructuring, and just destructuring in general) in Chapter 7 of my recent book JavaScript: The New Toys. Links in my profile if you're interested.